# Looking to develop my own small C++ browser that basically will display HTML, Javascript, and Flash, where to start?

Tags: c++, windows, linux, browser, open-source

I'm looking to start developing a browser (operating system isn't an issue, but preferring Linux or Windows). I'm just trying to figure out where to start. I know Visual Studio lets you drop a lightweight IE component into it, but I don't want IE's issues. I was hoping to start with a very basic mozilla build, but I cant seem to find one anywhere.

Does anyone know where I can find a good open source starting point OR how to start this on my own?

Comment: Do you want to develop a browser or do you want to use an existing browser control in your application?

Comment: You can't find the firefox source code? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Download_Mozilla_Source_Code

Comment: It's not that I couldn't find it, Im looking for something SUPER lightweight. Like barebones, and I just felt like firefox had too much. I'll look into it more though.

Comment: I'm looking to develop a browser as I don't want to be hindered by browser controls.

Comment: Webkit exists: http://www.webkit.org/. I don't know if it is what you are looking for.

Comment: You cannot make a *small* browser. It will be big and hard to make

Answer (score 2):

If you're not opposed to using Qt, then Qt's Webkit implementation could be a fairly clean start for cross-platform work:

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/examples-webkit.html

Note in particular the "Fancy Browser" sample:

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/webkit-fancybrowser.html

There are many customizations possible and ways of hooking the engine.  There's also support for Flash, though I've not tried that:

http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/31547-Flash-support-for-QT-Webkit-4-6

Although you can use Qt with other compilers/IDEs, the quickest way to get started is with Qt Creator.  After installing it there should only be a few clicks needed to get the QtWebkit examples building, on either Windows or Linux:

http://qt.nokia.com/products/developer-tools

Comment: I'm going to tackle this or use a barebones implementation of Apple's WebView.

Thanks for your help!